# problema ao instalar @pdftron/pdfnet-node

Tags: node.js, pdf, intellij-idea, npm-install

"""
npm i @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1

> @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 preinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\PASTAS\Estagio\pdfToImageFile\nodepdf\node_modules@pdftron\pdfnet-node
>   npm install node-pre-gyp

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

- node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
  added 66 packages from 25 contributors and audited 66 packages in 12.576s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 install C:\Users\user\Desktop\PASTAS\Estagio\pdfToImageFile\nodepdf\node_modules@pdftron\pdfnet-node
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build=false

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Remote end closed socket abruptly.
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.on_socket_end (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PASTAS\Estagio\pdfToImageFile\nodepdf\node_modules@pdftron\pdfnet-node\node_modules\
needle\lib\needle.js:480:17)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PASTAS\Estagio\pdfToImageFile\nodepdf\node_modules\@pdftron\pdfnet
-node\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build=false"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\PASTAS\Estagio\pdfToImageFile\nodepdf\node_modules@pdftron\pdfnet-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Remote end closed socket abruptly.
npm WARN nodepdf@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN nodepdf@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @pdftron/pdfnet-node@7.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-13T17_31_52_494Z-debug.log

"""

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, please check https://github.com/tomas/needle/issues/312 and linked tickets for possible workarounds